# How to set constraints for item below UITableView with variable height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I am trying to position a `UIButton` below a `UITableView` within a Vertical Stack View. But the vertical placement of the `UIButton` does not seem to be communicating with the bottom edge of the table.

I have been experimenting with different numbers of cells in the `UITableView`, but the button's position does not seem to change. For example, when there is one cell, the view looks like:

[View with one cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Nlz.png)

And when there are two cells, the view looks like:

[View with two cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH5Wo.png)

Everything is contained in a stack, which is shown below:

[Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncVL8.png)

Any thoughts on what is going on here? Really would appreciate any help

Comment: Try by setting tableView's height same as table's contentView height.

Answer (score 0):

You can add constraints:

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
```

If you want button to be always at bottom then add this constraint:

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true.
```

You are using storyboard or xib in that case you need to set constraint there.